# How to inquire data with data type as string using $gt in MongoDB?

Tags: database, string, mongodb, mongodb-query, type-conversion

I'm using MongoDB to check the data.
The data type of the **resturant_id** field in my database is composed of strings.
I would like to inquire data with this **resturant_id** over **40000000**.
What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste your sample data as images. Instead, post as valid json documents. Also, please check out [$toLong](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/)

Comment: Try using the _Collation_ option with `numericOrdering: true`. This allows the numeric data in strings to be compared as numbers.